# Triple integral bounded above by $z=6-x^2-y^2$ and below by $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: cylindrical-coordinates

[image: Plot of the two function]

Triple integral bounded above by $z=6-x^2-y^2$ and below by $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$
in addition: $x+y\geq0$

As I understand it I should find the volume of a kind of ice cream cone(see image)

My setup in cylindrial coordinates:

$\int\int\int\,r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta$

$0 \leq r \leq 2$ (as the intersection between the two plots are the unit cirle with radius $2$

the integral of $dz$ with limits from $z= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ to $z=6-x^2-y^2$

Integrate the angle $\displaystyle{-\frac{\pi}{4}\leq\theta\leq\frac{3\pi}{4}}$.

I can integrate this, but can't get the correct answer
 I am told in the problem to integrate the region

Triple integral $xdV$.

$dV$ must be $r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta$ but why the $x$ there?

Comment: If you are integrating using cylindrical coordinates, there shouldn't be any $x$ terms left after conversion.

Comment: The problem state that the region T is bounded above by z=6-x^2-y^2 and below by z=sqrt(x^2+y^2). That is the ice cream cone. Next: let D be a part of T that satisfies the condition x+y>=0. This restrict  the angle of integration. Then we are told to calculate the triple integral (x dV) over the region D.  As you understand, I am confused why the x is there as there should not be any left after the conversion.

Comment: The problem state that the region T is bounded above by z=6-x^2-y^2 and below by z=sqrt(x^2+y^2). That is the ice cream cone. Next: let D be a part of T that satisfies the condition x+y>=0. This restrict  the angle of integration. Then we are told to calculate the triple integral (x dV) over the region D.  As you understand, I am confused why the x is there as there should not be any left after the conversion.  By the way I see that after the conversion the lower limit of dz is r and the upper is 6 - r^2 (since r^2=x^2+y^2). I forgot to put that in the problem above

Comment: Is the question asking you to find the volume of the region bounded by the following bounds? Or is it asking you to  triple integrate $x$ over the region of integration? If the question is asking the latter of the two, that is why the $x$ is left there. By the way, when converting to cylindrical, $x = r \cos{\theta}$

Comment: when I integrate dz drom r to 6-r^2,dr from 0 to 2 and d(theta) from -pi/4 to 3pi/4 I get 16pi/3 which is not corrrect according to my professor. have I misunderstood the whole thing?

Comment: Thanks a lot: replacing x with rcos(theta) give the corrrect answer . I integrated by computer, now I have to do it bye hand. At least I am happy that I was able to set up the limits https://www.symbolab.com/solver/triple-integrals-calculator/%5Cint_%7B-%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B4%7D%7D%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B3%5Cpi%7D%7B4%7D%7D%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B2%7D%5Cint_%7Br%7D%5E%7B6-r%5E2%7Dr%5Ccdot%20cos%5Cleft(%5Ctheta%5Cright)rdzdrd%5Ctheta

Comment: Thanks a lot WaveX for your help. Converting the x to polar solved it. Now on to solve by hand

Comment: One more thing: integrate without x gives volume, I understand that  but with x, how to interpret that?

Comment: If you really want to get technical, you could potentially look at it as finding the "volume" under the hyperplane $w=x$ in the fourth dimension. Similarly as to how double integrating a function finds the volume underneath the surface within the specified bounds. Of course this is just one way to look at it, and I don't have the greatest of knowledge to answer that question the the fullest but I hope it helped :)

Comment: Thanks a lot  WaveX.. Fourth dimension, that's an interesting way to interpret it, and why not,: in linear algebra we deal with more than 3 dimension all the time